# Can we use Nullable(of T) for property using List<of T>?

Tags: vb.net, generics

In the below sample code, I have tried to use Nullable(of T) for DateTime and I want to use it same of the Dimensions property which is List(of Dimension).

```
 Private _duedate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
        Public Property DueDate() As Nullable(Of DateTime)
            Get
                Return _duedate
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of DateTime))
                _duedate = value
            End Set
        End Property

   Private _dimensions As List(Of Dimension)
            Public Property Dimensions() As List(Of Dimension)
                Get
                    Return _dimensions
                End Get
                Set(ByVal value As List(Of Dimension))
                    _dimensions = value
                End Set
            End Property
```

If we can then please any help on how can we do it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `List(Of Dimension?)` is not what you want I assume?

Comment: Just an fyi, but most of the time you don't want a Set option for List properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `Nullable(Of T)` for `List(Of T)`.  Simply use `List(Of T)` directly and use `Nothing` for the no value state.

The basic capability `Nullable(Of T)` provides is for value types to have a no-value state.  This concept is clearer in C# where there is a syntactic difference between no value `null` and default value `default(T)`.  In VB.Net though there is simply `Nothing` which represents both no value for reference types and default value for value types.